# Execute a shell command line in Java

Tags: java, linux, shell

I tried to execute a shell command in Java, but it's not working.

I can directly run this command on Linux(Ubuntu):

```
/bin/sh -c 'while true ; do java -jar /home/user/workspace/TCPClientNew/WebContent/NewClient.jar  192.168.138.1 6789 ; sleep 1 ; done'
```

but when I do this with Java, it never executes. It always shows "Not Found".
Here is my code:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc;

String[] commands = {"/bin/sh","-c","'while true ; do java -jar /home/user/workspace/TCPClientNew/WebContent/NewClient.jar "+" "+host+" "+port+ " ; sleep 1 ; done'"};
proc = rt.exec(command);
```

Can someone tell me why it's wrong?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Try to use ProcessBuilder Class and execute your command

Comment: @MiteshParmar thanks, but can you tell me why this is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The single quotes in the command line are there to prevent interpretation of the third argument by the shell that runs the command line. They are not needed in Java, as there's no command line shell anymore. Just remove the single quotes.

Comment: There's no "Thank you" on StackOverflow. Just accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code might helps you.

```
 try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/bash", "-c", "while true ; do java -jar /home/user/workspace/TCPClientNew/WebContent/NewClient.jar"+" "+host+" "+port+ " ; sleep 1 ; done");
            pb.start();
            } finally { 
         //  pb.close();
        }
```